# How do I center the ADAMS BLOG text to the center and have the other tabs to the left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how do I center the main title that says adams blog and have the other menu items exist to the right of it?
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FlexBox.
Give the following CSS commands to the parent element in the title and other menus:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

You can also use `space-around` or `space-evenly` instead of `space-between`.

Comment: This answer is incorreect, and does not do what is requested in the question. In the question, it is requested that the logo be centered on the  page, and this answer does not help with that.